# Why would GLCapabilities.setHardwareAccelerated(true/false) have no effect on performance?

Tags: opengl, hardware-acceleration, jogl

I've got a JOGL application in which I am rendering 1 million textures (all the same texture) and 1 million lines between those textures.  Basically it's a ball-and-stick graph.

I am storing the vertices in a vertex array on the card and referencing them via index arrays, which are also stored on the card.  Each pass through the draw loop I am basically doing this:

```
gl.glBindBuffer(GL.GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, <buffer id>);
gl.glBindBuffer(GL.GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, <buffer id>);
gl.glDrawElements(GL.GL_POINTS, <size>, GL.GL_UNSIGNED_INT, 0);

gl.glBindBuffer(GL.GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, <buffer id>);
gl.glBindBuffer(GL.GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, <buffer id>);
gl.glDrawElements(GL.GL_LINES, <size>, GL.GL_UNSIGNED_INT, 0);
```

I noticed that the JOGL library is pegging one of my CPU cores.  Every frame, the run method internal to the library is taking quite long.  I'm not sure why this is happening since I have called `setHardwareAccelerated(true)` on the `GLCapabilities` used to create my canvas.

What's more interesting is that I changed it to `setHardwareAccelerated(false)` and there was no impact on the performance at all.

Is it possible that my code is not using hardware rendering even when it is set to true?  Is there any way to check?

EDIT:

As suggested, I have tested breaking my calls up into smaller chunks.  I have tried using `glDrawRangeElements` and respecting the limits that it requests.  All of these simply resulted in the same pegged CPU usage and worse framerates.

I have also narrowed the problem down to a simpler example where I just render 4 million textures (no lines).  The draw loop then just doing this:

```
gl.glEnableClientState(GL.GL_VERTEX_ARRAY);
gl.glEnableClientState(GL.GL_INDEX_ARRAY);
gl.glClear(GL.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL.GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);
gl.glMatrixMode(GL.GL_MODELVIEW);
gl.glLoadIdentity();

<... Camera and transform related code ...>

gl.glEnableVertexAttribArray(0);
gl.glEnable(GL.GL_TEXTURE_2D);
gl.glAlphaFunc(GL.GL_GREATER, ALPHA_TEST_LIMIT);
gl.glEnable(GL.GL_ALPHA_TEST);  

<... Bind texture ...>

gl.glBindBuffer(GL.GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, <buffer id>);
gl.glBindBuffer(GL.GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, <buffer id>);
gl.glDrawElements(GL.GL_POINTS, <size>, GL.GL_UNSIGNED_INT, 0);

gl.glDisable(GL.GL_TEXTURE_2D);
gl.glDisable(GL.GL_ALPHA_TEST);
gl.glDisableVertexAttribArray(0);

gl.glFlush();
```

Where the first buffer contains 12 million floats (the x,y,z coords of the 4 million textures) and the second (element) buffer contains 4 million integers.  In this simple example it is simply the integers 0 through 3999999.

I really want to know what is being done in software that is pegging my CPU, and how I can make it stop (if I can).

My buffers are generated by the following code:

```
gl.glBindBuffer(GL.GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, <buffer id>);
gl.glBufferData(GL.GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, <size>
    * BufferUtil.SIZEOF_FLOAT, <buffer>,
    GL.GL_STATIC_DRAW);

gl.glVertexAttribPointer(0, 3, GL.GL_FLOAT, false, 0, 0);
```

and:

```
gl.glBindBuffer(GL.GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, <buffer id>);
gl.glBufferData(GL.GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER,
    <size> * BufferUtil.SIZEOF_INT,
    <buffer>, GL.GL_STATIC_DRAW);
```

ADDITIONAL INFO:

Here is my initialization code:

```
gl.setSwapInterval(1); //Also tried 0

gl.glShadeModel(GL.GL_SMOOTH);
gl.glClearDepth(1.0f);
gl.glEnable(GL.GL_DEPTH_TEST);
gl.glDepthFunc(GL.GL_LESS);
gl.glHint(GL.GL_PERSPECTIVE_CORRECTION_HINT, GL.GL_FASTEST);

gl.glPointParameterfv(GL.GL_POINT_DISTANCE_ATTENUATION,
        POINT_DISTANCE_ATTENUATION, 0);
gl.glPointParameterfv(GL.GL_POINT_SIZE_MIN, MIN_POINT_SIZE, 0);
gl.glPointParameterfv(GL.GL_POINT_SIZE_MAX, MAX_POINT_SIZE, 0);
gl.glPointSize(POINT_SIZE);

gl.glTexEnvf(GL.GL_POINT_SPRITE, GL.GL_COORD_REPLACE, GL.GL_TRUE);
gl.glEnable(GL.GL_POINT_SPRITE);

gl.glClearColor(clearColor.getX(), clearColor.getY(),
        clearColor.getZ(), 0.0f);
```

Also, I'm not sure if this helps or not, but when I drag the entire graph off the screen, the FPS shoots back up and the CPU usage falls to 0%.  This seems obvious and intuitive to me, but I thought that might give a hint to someone else.

Comment: Try turning off VSync and limiting your framerate manually to see if it's the routine that waits for the VSync on your monitor which does peg a core at 100% (a problem in both DirectX and OpenGL).

Comment: I tried turning off VSync too - assuming I'm doing it correctly - and still no change.  I called `gl.setSwapInterval(0)` to turn it off.

Comment: have you tried profiling to see exactly which call is using the most CPU time?

Comment: See my response to @MrCranky, but yes.  It's `com.sun.opengl.util.FPSAnimator$1.run()` and `javax.media.opengl.GLCanvas$DisplayOnEventDispatchThreadAction.run()` (each almost exactly 50%)

Comment: Let me amend that statement, that was before I changed the default profiler settings.  More specifically, the two functions are `javax.media.opengl.Threading.invokeOnOpenGLThread()` and `com.sun.opengl.impl.windows.WindowsOnscreenGLDrawable.swapBuffers()` - I'm looking into those deeper right now.

Comment: The wwapBuffers call would lend itself to the CPU usage VSync issue I pointed out.

Comment: @JonathanDickinson That test was done with vsync off.  It seems that the swapbuffers call is waiting on the graphics card to finish the rendering of the current frame, and that it is crushing the CPU (1 core anyway) while it waits.  Thus, I think I've found the cause of my problem, but I'm not sure if I can stop it.  Also, the graphics card seems to be so tied up with rendering my OpenGL scene that it looks like its dropping the refresh on my entire Windows desktop (also not ideal).

Comment: This is some really crazy stuff you are seeing. Usually with the VSync issue a 'good' engine gets the time within an acceptable range of the next refresh and then passes it off to the underlying framework (OpenGL/DX) to wait for the actual refresh. You might try something similar with this issue - i.e. wait in a loop until the device is ready in a more CPU-friendly loop.

Comment: @JonathanDickinson That sounds reasonable - any idea how to see if/when the graphics card is busy from JOGL?  I just did a test where I just threw a sleep for (1/estimated frame rate) in the code and the CPU usage dropped.  That's not ideal though, as the framerate may change often.  I also think I might be able to make the problem less of an issue when my scene is static, though I'm not entirely sure how.  I've posted a new question about that here: http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/25674/can-i-leverage-the-fact-that-my-scene-is-often-static-to-improve-opengl-jogl-p

Comment: Sorry, that's as far as I can help you as I am actually a DirectX developer - all I know is OGL has some of the same problems.

Comment: Yes, I'd definitely recommend using an accurate timer, measuring the amount of time you're spinning in the swap-buffers call, and adding in a short Sleep the next time around. E.g. if your swap/present is taking 40ms, then Sleep for 30ms and then call the swap/present. That will cut your CPU load massively. Bear in mind that Sleep on Windows platforms at least has a minimum amount: so if you want to Sleep for anything less than 10ms, just don't bother, because Sleep (1) or Sleep(0) will still sleep for about 10ms. I've used this to maintain a low CPU 30Hz framerate before.

Comment: @JonathanDickinson Can you summarize your comments into an answer so you can get some credit for it? :)  Just make sure that you mention SwapBuffers is waiting on the GPU to finish rendering the last frame.  I could answer the question myself, but you helped me come to the conclusion, so that wouldn't be fair.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is that the GPU was taking too long to render the frame and subsequent frames ended up doing a CPU intensive busy wait before moving onto the next frame.

The busy wait was occurring in:
`com.sun.opengl.impl.windows.WindowsOnscreenGLDrawable.swapBuffers()`

The solution was 2 fold.

First, to prevent frames from backing up I changed my FPSAnimator to have `scheduleAtFixedRate` as `false`.  That is:

`new FPSAnimator(canvas, 30, false);`

The second change was to render my entire scene into a Framebuffer Object and simply draw the Framebuffer Object to the screen each frame.  Since my scene is mostly static, I was able to use this to increase the FPS while my scene is not changing.  When the scene does change, I render it to the Framebuffer Object again.

Answer (score 3):

If you weren't using hardware acceleration at all you would be getting less than 1 fps.  Unless that applies we can discount that possibility.

My hunch is that your vertex pipeline has dropped back to software emulation.  You're saying that you've got one million lines and you're calling glDrawElements with GL_UNSIGNED_INT, which - depending on your hardware - may be overflowing your hardware maximum for number of vertexes per draw call and max vertex index.

Note that glDrawElements itself doesn't specify these maximums, but you can bet that they do exist in hardware.

To resolve this you can try splitting up your glDrawElements calls so that your indexes fit in unsigned shorts.  Yes, it's more draw calls, but it will fit within hardware limits for everything and won't choke your vertex pipeline.

Comment: I pulled the values of GL_MAX_ELEMENTS_VERTICES and GL_MAX_ELEMENTS_INDICES, and they are both 1,048,576.  This would seem to agree with your hunch.  Are you saying that I need to break my vertex array buffers (GL.GL_ARRAY_BUFFER) up into smaller chunks or just my index array buffers(GL.GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER)?  If I had to break both up into smaller chunks, that would be nightmarish for my current application...

Comment: You could get away with the indexes and just set new array pointers with different offsets.

Comment: Note that `MAX_ELEMENTS_VERTICES` and `MAX_ELEMENTS_INDICES` are for glDraw<b>Range</b>Elements. It has nothing to do with `glDrawElements`.

Comment: Yup, I've noted it, and have also noted that both glDrawElements and glDrawRangeElements predate hardware T&L.  Bottom line is that if a limit exists in hardware then the spec can say that the moon is a blue cube for all it matters, and this is a limit that exists in hardware.

Comment: I don't think this is it.  I've narrowed the problem down to a simpler test case, which is simply rendering 4 million textures.  When I draw them all in one glDrawElements call I get 19 FPS.  When I split it up into chunks of 750k indexed by an int, it drops to 17 FPS, when I split it up into chunks of 32k indexed by a short it drops to 11 FPS.  I also tried 32k chunks indexed by an int, it's still 11 FPS.  I believe the limits are for internal performance optimization of glDrawRangeElements only and performance reverts to that of glDrawElements if the conditions are not met.

Comment: The chosen answer and the comments here seem to agree with my last point: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6475418/a-question-about-gl-vertex-array

Answer (score 1):

My bet would be that your performance is not bound by GPU operations, and that hardware acceleration makes no difference because the amount of time spent doing the GPU work is dwarfed by 'something else'; be that marshalling on the driver side, something in the OpenGL libs itself, or even possibly your own code. The trouble is, figuring out what overhead is getting you isn't straightforward unless you know what's going on under the hood.

That diagnosis would be consistent with your reply to mh01's answer; increasing the number of draw calls to render the same primitives adds yet more overhead, while keeping the number of primitives drawn the same. Have you tried making the task less complex to see if there's one element of the problem that causes a massive drop in performance? E.g. does disabling textures but rendering the same amount of primitives work fine?

My advice would be to dig out a sampling profiler (something that breaks into your process every X microseconds and grabs the callstack), and see which module it's spending all this time in.

Comment: I ran `jvisualvm` and determined that the slowdown was not in my user code.  The functions using all the CPU are `com.sun.opengl.util.FPSAnimator$1.run()` and `javax.media.opengl.GLCanvas$DisplayOnEventDispatchThreadAction.run()`.  I have stripped the code down.  I tried disabling textures, depth testing, alpha testing, etc.  Nothing seemed to help performance at all.  Further, there shouldn't be much that needs marshalled.  If I understand correctly my code should simply tell the card the address and number of points to draw.  It's not like it's sending the whole buffer each frame.

Comment: The deeper functions called by those 2 functions are actually: `javax.media.opengl.Threading.invokeOnOpenGLThread()` and `com.sun.opengl.impl.windows.WindowsOnscreenGLDrawable.swapBuffers()`

Comment: Hmm, a spin-wait in swapBuffers is consistent with a heavy GPU load , so that probably rules my theory out.